# Using Unity to create a singleton that is used in my Class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a class that needs an instance of a HttpClient class, which I want to be instantiated only once i.e. Singleton

```
public interface IMyClass {}
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    private HttpClient client;
    public MyClass(HttpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
}


IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

How can I register the httpClient instance as a singleton to my `MyClass` can use it?

Comment: Why do you want to have a single instance of HttpClient ?

Comment: @Itsik
Most likely because HTTP client was designed to be used as a singleton. I personally don't recommend using it per-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx

Since there will be only one instance of your class, there will also one only one instance of HTTP client inside it.

Update:

In order to resolve HttpClient dependency itself, use

```
container.RegisterType<HttpClient, HttpClient>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

That way any class that needs HttpClient will receive the same instance of it. I'm not sure about the order of parameters, but basically you have to tell Unity 2 things - to register HttpClient as a singleton and to use its default constructor.

Comment: I want to use HttpClient in other classes also, not just in MyClass.

Comment: I don't see you registering the class HttpClient anywhere?  How would that work?

Comment: Would you like it to be Singleton for all classes or a separate instance for each of them?

Comment: Singleton for all classes that need a HttpClient.

Comment: In that case try to use RegisterType<HttpClient,HttpClient> with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. I don't have any Unity stuff right now so I can't guarantee that syntax is 100% correct.

Comment: I am getting this error ```The current type, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?```

Comment: It's because Unity tries to create HttpMessageHandler for you. You can specify the constructor directly using new InjectionConstructor() inside RegisterType to use a parameterless one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148349/discussion-between-vlad-stryapko-and-cool-breeze).