# Is there a way to implement IoC httpclient via Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a solution which has business service, business entities, data model layers, and an asp.net web API project. I am calling 3rd party web api in my business service layer. I followed this [link] ([Using Unity to create a singleton that is used in my Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912474/using-unity-to-create-a-singleton-that-is-used-in-my-class)) in order to use IoC via Unity but I am getting null for httpclient.

```
public class Utilities : IUtilities
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient;

        public Utilities(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }


        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallRazer(GameRequest gameRequest, string url)
        {

            //Convert request
            var keyValues = gameRequest.ToKeyValue();
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            //Call Game Sultan
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://test.com/"+url, content);
            return response;
        }
    }

    }
```

Here is Unity config:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
            // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IGameServices, GameServices>().RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUtilities, Utilities>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<HttpClient, HttpClient>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
        }
```

Game Service added.

```
public class GameServices : IGameServices
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        /// <summary>
        /// Public constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public GameServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a product
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestDto"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GamePurchase(RequestDto requestDto)
        {
            try
            {
                string htmlResponse = null;
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                {
                    //Transform DTO into GameRequest for calling Razer Initiate
                    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<RequestDto, GameRequest>(); });
                    var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                    var gameRequest = iMapper.Map<RequestDto, GameRequest>(requestDto);
                    //Create signature
                    gameRequest = Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequest, RequestType.Initiate);
                    //Unique reference ID
                    gameRequest.referenceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                    //Add request into database
                    _unitOfWork.GameRepository.Insert(gameRequest);

                    #region Call Razer initiate/confirm
                    response = await Utilities.CallRazer(gameRequest, "purchaseinitiation");

                    //Read response
                    htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var gameResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameResponse>(htmlResponse);
                    //Adding response into database
                    _unitOfWork.GameResponseRepository.Insert(gameResponse);
                    if (gameResponse.initiationResultCode == "00")
                    {
                        //Create signature
                        var gameConfirmRequest = Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequest, RequestType.Confirm);


                    }

                    #endregion

                    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
                    scope.Complete();

                }

                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

        }


        public enum RequestType
        {
            Initiate = 0,
            Confirm = 1

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting to all posted code and are you getting any exceptions?  You did not post the code that is calling the  Utilities method that is passing the httpClient so I can't tell why it is null.

Comment: @jdweng I added the Game Service code which calls Utilities.

Comment: Where is "new Utilities(client)"?

Comment: @jdweng I don't get what you mean? Would you please explain?

Comment: you need to instantiate the client before injecting, https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/10/reusing-httpclient-with-dependency-injection/

Comment: The class Utilities has a constructor that sets the client.  To call the constructor you need to have someplace in the code "new Utilities(client)".

Comment: @jdweng but if I make CallRazer method not static and instantiate Utilities where I am calling it then they become tightly coupled right?

Comment: The static method is using _httpClient which is set in the constructor.  If you do not call the constructor than _httpClient is going to be null when you call the static method.

Comment: @jdweng is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The you would have to pass to CallRazer the client in the parameter list.

Comment: @jdweng do you mean adding httpClient into GameServices and initialize it in the GameService constructor?

Comment: You did not post the code where the client connection is established.  All I'm saying is once you get the client you need to pass the client to the Utilities constructor to get it set.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand @jdweng HttpClient is used only inside of CallRazer. `var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://test.com/"+url, content); ` If I pass httpclient to the CallRazer method then I need to have httpclient in the place where I call it which is GameServices.

Comment: The Request (connection) must be made before the call to CallRazer.  That is the real issue.  You need to create a httpclient.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient